# Error: connect ENOENT /var/run/docker.sock when using node-docker-api

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-api

I have been trying to call docker from my Node.js application, and to do so I am using node-docker-api as described in the npm module documentation https://github.com/AgustinCB/docker-api. To test if I am able to interact with docker from Node.js I am running a small sample application given as a example in the documentation. But I am getting error as **{ Error: connect ENOENT /var/run/docker.sock**. The complete error message is shown below

**dockerOperations.js:**

```
'use strict';
const {Docker} = require('node-docker-api');
var Q = require('q');


var service = {}
service.runDockerCommand = runDockerCommand;
    function runDockerCommand() {
      console.log('inside runDockerCommand');
      var deferred = Q.defer();
      const docker = new Docker({ socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock' });
      console.log(docker);

      docker.container.create({
        Image: 'ubuntu',
        name: 'test'
      })
        .then(container => container.start())
        .then(container => container.stop())
        .then(container => container.restart())
        .then(container => container.delete({ force: true }))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

**Error**

```
{ Error: connect ENOENT /var/run/docker.sock
at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1170:14)
```

errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/var/run/docker.sock' }

Comment: Do you have the docker service running on the host machine? Does `/var/run/docker.sock` exist on the host? What OS is your host machine?

Comment: @MikeGorski: It's a windows machine, docker service is running but I am not able to find /var/run/docker.sock , is there any specific directory that I can look into?

Comment: According to this https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/faqs/#how-do-i-connect-to-the-remote-docker-engine-api it's `npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine`

Comment: Because of Windows file system, there is no such /var/run/docker.sock 
You need to map this path from docker to your Windows host

Comment: @Algeriassic: how can I do that?

Comment: @MikeGorski: I tried npipe option, but I am getting the same error

Comment: @abhi: docker run -d -v \\.\pipe\docker_engine:/var/run/docker.sock blahblah...

Answer (score 6):

I just faced the same issue. In order to solve it, you need to mount the docker socket of your host machine into a volume of your container. This should allow your script to access it to trigger containers. I personally use Docker Compose, here is an example how I did it, see line `volumes`:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
    graphql:
        container_name: mobydq-graphql
        restart: always
        image: mobydq-graphql
        build:
            context: ./graphql
        volumes:
            - //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        env_file:
            - ./.env
        depends_on:
            - db
        networks:
            - network
        command:
            [some command...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker on windows does not use unix sockets. You'll have to access the docker daemon over tcp. Try connecting to port 2375 over tcp.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#examples

Comment: I modified the socket path to 'tcp://0.0.0.0:2375', I am still getting the same error. Here is the line I modified :   const docker = new Docker({ socketPath: 'tcp://0.0.0.0:2375' });

Answer (score 1):

This can solve. (`node-docker-api@1.1.22`)

```js
const docker = new Docker({ socketPath: '//./pipe/docker_engine' })
```

(**not `npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine`**)